# How to show the location of each occourence of a char in a string?

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am working on a homework assignment. Here is my problem and attempted solution.

> Show the location of each occurence of the character "e" in the string "tx_val"

```
    tx_val="the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back";

    os=' ';  //output string
    eloc=' '; 

    for (i=0; i<tx_val.lastIndexOf('e');i++)
     {
    if(tx_val.indexOf('e')!= -1)
        {

            eloc=tx_val.indexOf('e') ; 
            os=os+eloc;
            i++;
        }   

      }
```

My Expected results: `2 24 29 34`

My results: `2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2`

I am not looking for an answer as much as for somebody to explain why my logic doesn't work and to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Use the second argument of indexOf.

Comment: `indexOf('e')` will *always* give you the *first* index of `e`. Use the [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to specify where to start searching from. Having said that, I wouldn't solve this problem how you are doing it.

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i` inside the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution might be something like this:

```
var lastIndex = tx_val.indexOf('e');
while (lastIndex > -1) {
    os += lastIndex + " ";
    lastIndex = tx_val.indexOf('e',lastIndex + 1);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. If you don't mind me asking. How did you determine to use a while loop? Is it just something you learn after years of experience?

Comment: Technically any `for` loop can be rewritten as a `while` loop and vice-versa. A `while` loop just feels like a more natural fit for what we are trying to do here since you want to loop *while* some condition is still true (there are still 'e''s to match). You could have written some like `for(var lastIndex = tx_val.indexOf('e'); lastIndex > -1; lastIndex = tx.val.indexOf('e',lastIndex + 1))` and it should work the same. But I don't personally like `for` loops that do more than just simple addition or subtraction on each loop. YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

When called with a single argument on the same string, [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) will keep returning the same index every time.

The first argument of `indexOf()` is the substring to be matched. The second optional argument is the index to start the search form. Unless you pass this argument, the result will not change between each iteration.

It also is incorrect to assume that the loop should have an `i` iterator equal to the `lastIndexOf()` value. That would only make the loop run many redundant iterations, as the number of matches is certainly not equal to the value of the matching indexes (unless the string is only made of `e` characters). In other words, if you had only one match in index `24`, the loop would still repeat 23 times for no reason.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer/Comment. I have revised my code and receive the 2nd,3rd 4th etc.  argument of indexOf(). Your point about the redundant loop iterations is spot on. How do I go about determining how to define the second argument of my for loop to only loop the desired number of times?

Comment: No problem. @MattBurland is indeed the correct solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Others already provided the solution (second parameter of `indexOf`).

I'll just leave this line here

```
tx_val.replace(/e/g, function(str, i) {os = os + ' ' + i});
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to split your string into an array of individuals characters, you parse it and store the matching indexes in another (output) array?